# Python, return html file generated by business logic in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a Rest API that can receive data from a user, run some business logic on it and return as a response an HTML File that is generated based on the data passed in.

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django import forms

# Create your models here.

areas = [
    ('210', '210'),
    ('769', '769'),
    ('300', '300')
]


class LocationInfo(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Latitude",
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    longitude = models.FloatField(name="GDT1Longitude",
                                  unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                  help_text="Enter the location's Longitude, second when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                  default=1)
    gdt2_lat = models.FloatField(name="GDT2Latitude",
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    gdt2_lon = models.FloatField(name="GDT2Longitude",
                                 unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                 help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                 default=1)
    uav_lat = models.FloatField(name="UavLatitude",
                                unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                default=1)
    uav_lon = models.FloatField(name="UavLongitude",
                                unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False,
                                help_text="Enter the location's Latitude, first when extracting from Google Maps.",
                                default=1)

    uav_elevation = models.FloatField(name="UavElevation",
                                      max_length=100, default=1,
                                      blank=False,
                                      help_text="Enter the above ~Sea Level~ planned uav Elevation. "
                                      )

    area = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=areas,
    )

    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'date_added'
```

```py
# serializers.py
from .models import LocationInfo
from rest_framework import serializers


class LocationInfoSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LocationInfo
        fields = (
            'id', 'GDT1Latitude', 'GDT1Longitude',
            'GDT2Longitude', 'GDT2Latitude',
            'UavLatitude', 'UavLongitude', 'UavElevation',
            'date_added'
        )
```

```py
# views.py
class LocationInfoViewSet(ViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.filter(id=1).values()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = self.queryset.reverse()[0]
        serialized_data = LocationInfoSerializer(data, many=False)
        points = list(serialized_data.data.values())

        gdt1 = (points[1], points[2])
        gdt2 = (points[3], points[4])
        uav = (points[5], points[6], points[-2])

        # My business logic which returns an HTML File based on the data passed in.
        data = main(gdt1, gdt2, uav)
     # I got stuck here.
```

All I'm missing here is how to open the generated HTML file in the browser automatically.

The logic script contains two options, one is to save the HTML file and stop and one opens it automatically in the browser ( I thought of somehow utilizing it).

My logic script

```
# main.py

import numpy as np
from Project_Level.angle_condition import MeetAngleCond
from Project_Level.plot_folium import PlotOnMap
from Project_Level.utils import convert_to_xy
from .dataframes import GetDataToGeoPandas
from .positions_data_collecting import PositionsData


def main(gdt1, gdt2, uav):
    # Get the complete latitude, longitude, lists.
    positions_data = PositionsData(gdt1=gdt1,
                                   gdt2=gdt2,
                                   uav=uav)
    full_lat_lon_list, lat_list, lon_list = positions_data.calculate_list_lens()

    # Get cartesian coordinates for every point.
    gdt1_xy = np.asarray(convert_to_xy(gdt1))
    gdt2_xy = np.asarray(convert_to_xy(gdt2))

    # Get the angle for every point in f_lat_lon_list
    angles_list = MeetAngleCond()
    plot_angles_list = angles_list.create_angles_list(lat_lon_list=full_lat_lon_list,
                                                      arrayed_gdt1=gdt1_xy,
                                                      arrayed_gdt2=gdt2_xy,
                                                      uav_elev=uav[-1])

    get_final_lists = GetDataToGeoPandas()
    lat_lon_a, lat_lon_b, optimal = get_final_lists.create_gpd_and_final_lists(angles_list=plot_angles_list,
                                                                               lat_list=lat_list,
                                                                               lon_list=lon_list)
    plot = PlotOnMap(lat_lon_a=lat_lon_a,
                     lat_lon_b=lat_lon_b,
                     optimal=optimal)
    plot.create_map(mid_point=gdt1, zoom=13)
    plot.plot_gdt_and_triangulation(gdt1=gdt1, gdt2=gdt2, uav=uav)
    plot.plugins()
    # option 1: save the html file in the directory.
    map_file = plot.return_html_link()

    # option 2: open it automatically in the browesr.
    # map_file = plot.auto_open(html_map_file='index.html')

    return map_file
```

Comment: If you don't need to save `LocationInfo`s into the database, by the way, you really don't need the model and a `ModelSerializer`; a basic `Serializer` will do.

Comment: Check - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

Comment: @AKK Yes, I know, but I do want to save them so that every time a user will want to display the same map, he will just pull the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add below code to view and see if it works for you.

```
return render(request, main(gdt1, gdt2, uav))
```

Here your function main(gdt1, gdt2, uav) should return a HTML file.

Approach 2:
Save html file to a specific path as filename.html and simply add below line to view.

```
return render(request, 'path/filename.html')
```

Comment: When I do this and input data, nothing happens, I also checked the index.html (the template to fill) and it wasn't updated at all.

Comment: Hi @yovelcohen, Please see if approach 2, works for you. You just need to save file to specific path (you are doing it already as part of Option 1). Just render the newly create html.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your `PlotOnMap()` class's writing API to

- accept a filename, you can use a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` that you can then read into a Django response; or
- accept an open file-like to write to, you can use an `io.BytesIO` to write to that you can then use as the `content` of a Django response.

This assumes the HTML file output is self-contained; if it's not (e.g. it needs external stylesheets or scripts), you would probably need to make it so, or generate a ZIP file to contain everything.

Comment: if the HTML File is a folium map which uses sources such as jquery, bootstrap and github repos it counts as not self-contained?

Comment: No, that's fine.